# z-index not working when transforming both psuedo element and parent

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Current I am trying to translate a parent element 10px on both the X & Y axis while transforming an `::after` the equal amount in the other directions (this is to simulate the experience of the pseudo element moving nowhere). I expected this to be fairly trivial, however, the `::after` does not want to remain behind it's parent while being transformed.
I assumed making a new stacking context would work, and I've never run into this issue before (having years of CSS experience).

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

button {
  padding: .75rem 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: ease all .15s;
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: ease all .15s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
}

button:hover::after {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Fun Button</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <button type="button">Fun Button!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/#stacking-order-within-the-same-stacking-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix to this is to consider the other pseudo element to create the grey background and you make both of them belong to the same stacking context initially (by adding `z-index` to button) so you won't have any issue when adding transform

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

button {
  padding: .75rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  transition: ease all .15s;
}

button::after,
button::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: ease all .15s;
}
button::before{
  z-index:-1;
  background-color: #eee;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
}

button:hover::after {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Fun Button!</button>
```